# How is it appropriate for me to be post-banned after a downvoted question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, post-ban

I don't like that after asking six questions, five of which having 0 votes, then one question gets -2 and I can't ask any more. How fair is this and why do such absurd rules exist?

Comment: Absurd? Excuse us for wanting to maintain quality. If you got a question ban, it is because the quality of your question is low - if you improve the questions in the manner outlined in the linked article (on the ban message), the ban will end up being lifted.

Comment: absurd is when you get that for 1 question marked -2 out of 6 and u cant post

Comment: You don't get evaluated based on that one question. You get evaluated for your overall history. This question tipped the scale but is by no means the only cause. And please don't call users idiots. I'll gladly help you out, but not with such language.

Comment: i am very angry that because someone couldnt understand something i cant post

Comment: Looking at your questions, I would say that understanding them (or a lack of understanding by the other users) is not likely to be the main cause for the downvotes.

Comment: @gordon, you have the wrong attitude here. If people don't understand what you're saying, _you need to spend more time explaining yourself clearly_. If you're seeking help, it's your job to make it easy for people to understand you. The two first comments you posted on Bart's answer are terrible in terms of explaining what you're asking.

Comment: i dont understand why some ppl are so egoist

Comment: i dont think i have forced anyone to answer the question but stopping a user from asking is pathethic of a policy.if needed u may fix a filter like auto deleting the post of the "faulty" user after a day if it receives no answers

Comment: but i think u ppl are too idk the exact word to find gentler solutions to problems of "vampire" something term u used on that page

Comment: i am beginning to hate ppl just because of you ppl.

Comment: @gordon Stop it. Do you want help or do  you want to complain and whine? If it's the latter, let me know. Then we can close this deal as "not constructive" and all move on.

Comment: i dont want to do anything any further thank you. just let me know when can i ask a question

Comment: @gordon If you don't improve, you won't ever be able to any more. This does not time out. Try reading the link you received. And read the FAQ. [I told you before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163578/why-didnt-i-get-the-analytical-badge#comment473881_163578) to actually do so instead of hunt for easy badges.

Comment: You also have two posts that you deleted yourself, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291935/how-to-add-marquee-to-one-div-element-in-css) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277750/dividing-webpage-using-div-and-css-html). The latter one you defaced before you deleted it, which doesn't look very good. Self-deleted questions count against you as well, so it's not just one or two questions factoring in here.

Answer (score 11):

The post-ban is in place to make sure a certain level of quality is maintained on the site. It forces users who do not overall positively contribute to the site to re-evaluate the quality of their contributions and improve them, before they are allowed to fully participate again. It's not all that absurd and is part of what maintains the quality this site has.

Two of your questions have been closed. One was downvoted. The rest did not achieve a positive score. That's not a great average. I don't know if you deleted anything else. Or if anything else got deleted? All you can do now is follow the advice given to you in the link.

Improve what you have contributed so far. And try to positively contribute in ways still possible to you. With a bit of effort you should be able to fully participate again in no time.

For you specifically, [one of the closed questions was a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295919/escaping-single-quote-double-quote-in-javascript). Unfortunate perhaps, but preventable by putting some effort into searching the site for previous content on the topic.

The [other closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294359/effects-on-mouse-movement-canvas) doesn't really ask a question related to a practical problem you face. You state what you want, and that's about it. Ideally the site's questions should contain what you have done, and where you are stuck. If you haven't really gotten anywhere yet, your question might simply not be appropriate for the site.

Overall your questions can do with a bit of love and care. Proper capitalization, proper phrasing. And above all clarity. Think of it like this: You are not merely asking a question to solve your immediate problem. You are also trying to generate content which will benefit future users. And the more clear you are in your description, the more chance others have to find a solution to their problem which is similar to yours. So put in a bit of effort.

Don't be too discouraged. With a bit of care you should be out of the ban in no time, if there are no skeletons in your closet.

Comment: how can i add a link please help

Comment: Add a link? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: hyperlink. url to a webpage

Comment: Have a look at the [markdown editing help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) which contains a full explanation of how to format content on the site, including links. Alternatively you can simply highlight the text you want to be a link and click on the little globe with an arrow on it in the editor. A window will the pop up where you can enter the address you want to link to.

Comment: i keep getting Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
Sorry, posts can't contain that content.

Comment: yes i did that globe thing and the url was created but when i clicked on submit i get the above error. i was trying to edit that closed question by posting a relevant link

Comment: What was the link? Could you put in a comment below? Perhaps format it as code...

Comment: Creating a canvas to load an image and distorting it at the position of the mouse to create ripples. This effect is very easy to implement inside an container but I need this for whole of background. I strongly suggest people to google this before closing a question as cannot be understood. Check [this][1]

  [1]: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=html%205%20canvas%20creating%20ripple%20like%20effect

Comment: this is the entire edit i tried to make

Comment: @gordon LMGTFY is banned from the site. You are not allowed to use it. It is often seen as offensive or insulting. Don't use it.

Comment: @gordon Egoist? Please have a look at yourself. It's not always somebody else's fault. The fact is that the overall quality of your contributions is not good. But I'm sure you can improve. If you want I can give you some interesting links on how to ask a good question. If you understand those, you'll also see where your posts are problematic. It will take some effort, but let me know if you're willing to put in the effort.

Comment: @gordon: what you did there is plain rude and stupid. If you know what to google for, then just google it yourself and build your solution. A LMGTFY is pretty much the most stupid thing you could do if you're seeking help (or any kind of respect) from others.

Comment: @Mat you are telling me about respect? after using"stupid" in your comment?

Comment: @gordon Don't draw this out. You've called users "idiots" above. Walk away from this one and focus your efforts on more constructive things.

Comment: aha! i did but I haven't cried about respect also

Comment: this guy talks about respect while using stupid in the same sentence.  and thanks to you, I have multiple questions in negative. your intentions are different from the polite talk you do

Comment: when I get back to my work station I will answer all my questions and u will see how resourceful they are.

Comment: Thanks to me? What on earth did I do besides spend my valuable free time trying to help you out? I should have known better really, after your earlier posts. Could have more productively used some of my spare time. Good luck with answering your own questions.

Comment: except the one involving quotes. that is only one I think could have been downmarked

Comment: yes, I will answer my own questions because I am not an egoist like some here.................

Comment: @gordon: if you don't listen to the advice people give you, and don't even seem to realize that quite a few people have been trying to help you despite your attitude, I don't know anything more we could do. Calling people here egoists is another _stupid_ move on your part. I'm not showing disrespect by saying this. I respect you enough to continue (futilely apparently) to get you to read the advice you've been given and try to think about what you're writing and the attitude you're displaying.