# Does it make sense restricting someone from asking questions?

Tags: discussion

What sense does it make restricting users from asking questions when the sole purpose of being here is to ask questions?

Sometimes, the administrators might not understand the questions asked due to language differences and background, but that doesn't mean others do not.

I have seen cases where some administrators close questions simply because they do not understand them. Meanwhile I and my friends understand the questions asked by the users.

Isn't this closed-mindedness and myopic?

Members come here restless in a bid to finding solutions, but some administrators would close their questions or restrict them from asking further because they think they aren't professionals. This to me is arrant nonsense.

Why not let users achieve their purpose here?

I have been to different sites, but I have never seen a site with system administrators as self-centered and arrogant as Stack Overflow.

Comment: "I have seen cases where some admins close questions simply because they do not understand them," Can you provide examples of this? Often it is the one saying this that doesn't understand the site. Also, the "admins" here are just other users https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's only a rant, and not a constructive question.

Comment: You misunderstood the purpose of these sites. It's drowned out by the big, bold 'ask questions, get answers', but the [tour](https://stackexchange.com/tour) does state the purpose: Build a libary of high quality questions and answers. Now that that misconception is out of the way, [this blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/) should make sense to you too: "**Asking questions is a privilege, not a right.**. If you haven’t been able to prove that your contributions to Stack Overflow make it at least … not-worse … then we reserve the right to refuse your questions."

Comment: Looking at your profile I see lots of discussions in the comment section and very few improvements to those questions.  Additionally, when you last submitted a question, you were warned your past questions were not well received.  I also see a pattern of asking a question and in a very short amount (minutes to a few hours) of time you then discovering your own solution. While answering your own question is wonderful, it makes me believe, your asking the question to quickly. You do know that a question banned is determined by a algorithm and happens automatically?

Comment: To answer your question, it makes total sense, to make you slow down.  How many of your questions have been deleted? Find it hard to believe you only asked 5 questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is it appropriate for me to be post-banned after a downvoted question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163592/how-is-it-appropriate-for-me-to-be-post-banned-after-a-downvoted-question)

Comment: Don't vandalize your questions.

Comment: I don't need to understand the tenets of administration. Administration is boring, numbers, accounts, debit, credit... I moderate. Much more fun. And I *do* understand that 'don't vandalize your questions' is a tenet of moderation :D

Comment: @CEO - Tinkeringbell is literally a moderator of this community, out of everyone that has shared feedback with you, they are literally the one individual who should be telling you what NOT to do.  Vandalizing your contributions are not allowed on any Stack Exchange community.

Comment: You have the following 6 deleted questions: [Q1](//stackoverflow.com/q/68774922), [Q2](//stackoverflow.com/q/68739204), [Q3](//stackoverflow.com/q/68725403), [Q4](//stackoverflow.com/q/68700369), [Q5](//stackoverflow.com/q/68672554), and [Q6](//stackoverflow.com/q/68654483). If you can't ask new questions, please read **[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583)**

Comment: You also have the following 13 deleted answers: [A1](//stackoverflow.com/a/69087242), [A2](//stackoverflow.com/a/69065423), [A3](//stackoverflow.com/a/69062923), [A4](//stackoverflow.com/a/69062646), [A5](//stackoverflow.com/a/69061703), [A6](//stackoverflow.com/a/69053106), [A7](//stackoverflow.com/a/69050755), [A8](//stackoverflow.com/a/69004359), [A9](//stackoverflow.com/a/68839900), [A10](//stackoverflow.com/a/68824463), [A11](//stackoverflow.com/a/68824387), [A12](//stackoverflow.com/a/68693522), and [A13](//stackoverflow.com/a/68661405).

Comment: Even at below 50 reputation points you can comment on your own posts - there isn't any need to use edits or answers for that. See also *"[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)"*.

Comment: Re *"I have never seen a site with system administrators as self-centered and arrogant as Stack Overflow"*: Don't you see the irony in that statement?

Comment: 'the sole purpose of being here is to ask questions?' ....ok, so who is going to answer them?

Answer (score 12):

One of the things we need to optimise is putting questions that people can answer in front of those people who can answer them. If we, instead, show those answerers streams of poor quality questions then

- they won't have time to answer the good quality questions they could otherwise answer.
- they will eventually leave the site altogether because scrolling through poor quality questions is not an interesting use of their time.

So we restrict people from continually asking poor quality questions when there's no sign that they are going to improve. You get several chances and warnings if you're not improving.

If you think a question needs improvement rather than closure then edit it into shape, but be careful not to make assumptions as you might then not be solving the issue that the OP actually has. In such cases closure signals to the OP that they need to add that missing information so the question can be reopened.

Our aim is to become a place of high quality questions that are useful to others. If there's a question that doesn't fit that criteria then it may well not belong here.

And a final note is that very few questions are closed by admins. They are mostly closed by other users, likely those very people that also spend time answering questions.